# Copy a string on a structure element in C

Tags: c, structure

I don't understand why my string is not copied.

The strings structures are similar to this one "KS 2H 5C JD TD"

Here is my code (the comments are all that I tried (`memcpy` and `strcpy`)):

```
typedef struct Hand Hand;
struct Hand {
    char *cards;
    double power;
};
Hand* initHand(char *set){
    Hand *hand = malloc(sizeof(*hand));
    if(hand == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    char card[5][3];
    //strcpy(hand->cards,*cards);
    int i=0;
    char *p = strtok (set, " ");

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        card[i] = p;
        printf("%s\n",p);
        p = strtok (NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }

    hand->power=0;
}
```

I was willing to copy every 2 letters in an array with `strtok` (this is what I wanna do); then I tried to copy the whole string.

Comment: The assignment `card[i] = p;` won't work; you'd need to use `strcpy()` — `strcpy(card[i], p);`.

Comment: You never allocate any memory for `char *cards` to point to

Comment: @jonathan Leffler i did change it but it still doesn't work , (i also tried to delete barely everything inside my initHand function and i noticed that the error persist until i delete this `char *p = strtok (set, " ");`

Comment: There are more problems in the code than that.  The lack of memory for `hand->cards` diagnosed by @UnholySheep is also a problem, as is the fact that you assign nothing to `hand->cards`.  In fact, you probably need to use a different type for the `cards` member.  You could use an array of `char *`, or something similar (whereupon `hand->cards[i] = p;` might be valid — but you still have to worry about space for the data (you can't store them long term in the local variable `card` because it vanishes when the function returns.  Frankly, you should use `char cards[5][3];` in the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot. I understood my mistakes:

Mistakes:

- I didn't know that strtok is a destructive function (I was trying to edit a readonly data since I was using a constant).
- I didn't allocate memory for `char *cards`

Solution:

- make a copy of the set.
- allocate memory.

Here's the code that worked for me:

```
struct Hand {
    char cards[5][3];
    double power;
};


Hand* initHand(char *set){
    Hand *hand = malloc(sizeof(*hand));
    if(hand == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    char copy_set[15]="";
    strcpy(copy_set,set);

    char **str = (char**) malloc(5*sizeof(char*));
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        str[i]= (char) malloc(3*sizeof(char));
    }
    strcpy(hand->cards,str);

    int i=0;
    char *p = strtok (copy_set, " ");

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(hand->cards[i], p);
        p = strtok (NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }
    
    hand->power=0;
    return hand;
}
```

Comment: That's much better.  However, the code shown requires a C++ compiler (the type `Hand` is not defined in C, though it is in C++).  Also, the cast `(char)` on the `malloc()` in the loop generates a compiler warning, at minimum.  The call `strcpy(hand->cards, str)` doesn't compile cleanly.  It's not clear how you expect to free the space allocated to `str`.  Indeed, at the moment, I'm not sure you need `str` at all. There are still quite a lot of problems to resolve.

Comment: Yeaah I know , but I don't know what should I do instead of strcpy(hand->cards, str) maybe memcpy ? , to free the space allocated to str I use this after strcpy                            `    for(int i = 0 ; i<3; i++){
        free(str[i]);
    }
    free(str);`

Comment: See my answer for a suggested resolution of the issues I raised.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is reasonably correct code — a relatively simple modification of the code shown in revision 2 of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63925671/2) by the OP.  There's always room for improvement, of course.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Hand
{
    char cards[5][3];
    double power;
};

typedef struct Hand Hand;

extern Hand *initHand(const char *set);

Hand *initHand(const char *set)
{
    Hand *hand = malloc(sizeof(*hand));
    if (hand == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    char copy_set[15] = "";
    strcpy(copy_set, set);

    int i = 0;
    char *p = strtok(copy_set, " ");

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(hand->cards[i++], p);
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    hand->power = 0;
    return hand;
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    Hand *hand = initHand("KS 2H 5C JD TD");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("Card %d: [%s]\n", i, hand->cards[i]);
    printf("Power:  %.2f\n", hand->power);

    free(hand);
}
```

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63924529/copy-a-string-on-a-structure-element-in-c#comment113046387_63925671), the variable `str` isn't needed.  With the revised structure, there is no need to allocate extra cards.  I've marked the string input as `const`.  Arguably, it would be better to do a dynamic memory allocation for `copy_set` (remembering to release the copy too), or at least check that the given data will fit in the allocated space.  It would probably be better to print an error message before unilaterally exiting on a memory allocation failure.  It is good to check for the failure.  It is not good to exit with saying why.  It would probably be better to return `NULL` on failure, and then let the calling code detect and handle the problem.

There's a simple test program attached to the code too.

Be cautious about using `strtok()`; it is dangerous to use it in library functions.  You should generally use `strtok_r()` (POSIX) or `strtok_s()` (Microsoft) for preference.